# How to get the width/height/length of a mesh in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh, collada

I been researching various places about trying to get the width and height of a mesh but I have been able to find anything that works. I have a collada model that I imported and all I want to do is get the dimension of it in Webgl/Three.js Units so that I can calculate collision in my simple game. So how would I go about getting the width and height of a mesh in THREE.js?

Comment: Please show what you attempted in order for others to be able to help.

Comment: Can someone tell me why I got -rep? I just want to know to not do it again on my future questions

Comment: You got negative reputation because someone down voted your question.  A down vote is meant to mean "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: Thank You! I appreciate that you answered :D Also I couldnt add the code before since I was doing this on a tablet, but vincent posted the perfect answer :D

Comment: You're welcome.  You may want to still add the code because otherwise, your question is on its way to being closed.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If you're ok with a basic bounding box, you can use a [THREE.Box3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.getSize)

```
let measure = new THREE.Vector3();
let box = colladaModel.getSize(measure);
console.log( measure );
```

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution, i'll try it when i have a chance and i'll tell u how it went! 

Comment: I used it and it worked perfectly, thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't give correct dimensions

Comment: hi @Tarun, can you explain in which conditions it does not work ?

Comment: do I need to somehow normalize values in matrix? Id like to flip object on x axis and move its -x_width ... flip is okay, bot move seems incorect

Comment: Just to keep it up two date: `size` method name was changed to `getSize`

Comment: thank you @KrzysztofGrzybek, I've updated the code.

Comment: but if the box(for example a text mesh) is rotated, the size is no more the exact width/height of that text.

Comment: Seems like Box3().getSize() has updated usage. A Vector3 needs to be passed into it as an argument. See here for implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819811/1757149

Comment: Thank you @A__ I've updated the code.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, throws this error:
this.objects[0].getSize is not a function