# What is the proper use of threejs Box3().getSize() method?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Everywhere on stackoverflow et al seem to agree that the proper use of the [`Box3() getSize()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.getSize) method is as follows:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

let cubeBoundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( cube );
let boxSize = cubeBoundingBox.getSize();
console.log("BoxSize: " + boxSize);
```

However this doesn't seem to be the case. See the error in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/8L5dczmf/3/

I can see in  the [three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Box3.getSize) that `getSize()` *is* in fact supposed to be used this way... unless I'm reading `.getSize ( target : Vector3 ) : Vector3` incorrectly. What is wrong with the code in the fiddle above then?

Comment: You should put the error directly in your question body. I thought the issue was the missing `target` param to `getSize`, but appears that it's actually that `getSize()` doesn't exist (althought `size()` does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're expected to pass in a vector into which the result will be written:

```js
// ...

let boxSize = new THREE.Vector3();
cubeBoundingBox.getSize(boxSize);

console.log("BoxSize: " + boxSize);
```

The intention here is that you can [pool your `Vector3` objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), and re-use them cheaply without making tons of garbage for the GC to clean up.